# Is it possible use $route to specify the contents of a filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, router

I am making an angularJS app that uses ng-repeat and a combination of filters as a simple type of controller. I did this so that users could both search and click their way through the site.

My side-bar nav looks like this:

```
<li><a ng-click="navFilter = {type: 'section1'}" >Section 1</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="navFilter = {type: 'section2'}" >Section 2</a></li>
<li><a ng-click="navFilter = {type: 'section3'}" >Section 3</a></li>
```

Which is also works with a search filter:

```
<input ng-click="Filter = null" type="text" ng-model="searchFilter">
```

When the user clicks on the search box, "Filter" the filter triggered by the side-bar nav is set to null and the user can search all contents of the site.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:navFilter | filter:searchFilter">
    <div>{{item.title}}</div>
    <div>{{item.body}}</div>
</div>
```

I am concerned about what happens when a user hits the back button. Is there an "Angular" way to configure a router such that when a user hits back, the URL causes the filter to go to its previous state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support browser buttons, better to add the filters in the query string parameters. Then use `$routeParams` to extract the filters to apply. Set the `searchFilter` and `navFilter` in the controller using these routeParams.

This would cause view reload but this can fixed by setting `$routeProvider` `reloadOnSearch=false`. See documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)